# Does Microsoft provide any API to access Macro enabled Excel files

Tags: python, api, checkbox, macros, radio-button

I am trying to create a JSON file by getting data from a macro enabled Excel file which has radio buttons and checkboxes. Can anyone tell me if MS provides any API to do so or how I can do it otherwise.

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8pQK.jpg)

Comment: Microsoft exposes excel functionality to all of its languages. Just the tip of the iceberg is, say, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.windows. That was just a quick internet search. You can use C/C++/VBA/C#/PowerShell/Python and etc... Unfortuantely this is far off of what stackoverflow is about. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I wanted it in python. This is VB.

Comment: You should learn about python's [win32 extensions](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/). As I said, you can use VB, python or a dozen other tools. Once you learn how the win32 extensions work, you can use docs from other tools to find what you want. You won't find complete docs for python itself.